# Proof help-- Is the function $f: \mathbf{Z}_5 \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}_{30}$ given by $f(x)=6x$ a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Is the function $f: \mathbf{Z}_5  \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}_{30}$ given by $f(x)=6x$ a ring homomorphism?\

Note that the definition of a ring homomorphism:
a ring A to a ring B is a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ satisfying the identities
$f(x_1 + x_2)= f(x_1)+f(x_2)$
and
$f(x_1 \times x_2)= f(x_1) \times f(x_2)$\

if $f(x)=6x$ and we let $a,b \in \mathbf{Z}_5$
then $f(a)+f(b)= 6a+6b$
$=6(a+b)$
$f(a+b)$
Also
$f(a)f(b)=6a \times 6b$
$=36ab$
$=6ab(\mod 30)$
$=f(ab)$
Thus by definition Ring Homorphism, f is a ring homomorphism.

Any suggestions on improving this?
Is there any other way one would go about this? I think I could draw on the fact their isomorphic, but I think that would be a longer proof?

Comment: Note that this depends on your definition of a ring. Often the term *ring* is short for *unital ring* (meaning it has a unit $1$), and a *ring homomorphism* is a *unital ring homomorphism*, meaning that it maps $1 \mapsto 1$. By these more restrictive definitions, your map is **not** a ring homomorphism since $1 \mapsto 6 \neq 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack: This is one of the reasons that the unital assumption is bad. Another reason is that most ideals of rings are not subrings.

Comment: For commutative rings, the unital assumption is quite common. So I suspect the "expected" answer for this homework is as Sammy said. Of course, this depends on the lecture. So did you check the definitions given in your lecture?